# Creating a dictionary of lists from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary of lists based on a pandas dataframe, I need a dictionary of lists to pass for my Plotly dashboard

```
In:
df.head()
Model    Make
Ford     F-150
Ford     Escape
Ford     Mustang
Jeep     Grand Cherokee
Jeep     Wrangler
```

I found `df.to_dict()` orients by column header but I need to orient based on neighboring row value. Is the only way to do this by re-shaping my dataframe into columns by Model with their respective makes under them?

```
Out:
makes_by_model= {
    'Ford': ['F-150', 'Escape', 'Mustang'],
    'Jeep': ['Wrangler', 'Grand Cherokee']
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), aggregate to lists, return a `rec.array` with [`to_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html) and construct a dictionary from the result:

```
dict(df.groupby('Model').agg(list).to_records())
# {'Ford': ['F-150', 'Escape', 'Mustang'], 'Jeep': ['Grand Cherokee', 'Wrangler']}
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! I realized after i mixed up make and model in my original post